# How would I do the following logic using LINQ

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq, c#-4.0, lambda, logic

I have an object with a list of datetime items. I have another list that has a property

I want to select the datetime items in the list that is in the object only if it matches one of the items in the other list. I am able to get the items but I don't know how to basically write "if the current item matches any of the items in this list".

The LINQ so far is like

```
from item in ObjectWithList.DateList
from compareItem in OtherDateTimeList
where item = //Here is there I run into trouble, how would I loop through the compareitems?
```

thanks

**EDIT**
I need this done in this LINQ as this is only a section of the over all LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ObjectWithList.DateList.Intersect(OtherDateTimeList)
```

**EDIT**

If must be a Linq query, and you don't want to use Intersect, try this:

```
var mix = from f in ObjectWithList.DateList
          join s in OtherDateTimeList on f equals s
          select f;
```

or

```
var mix = from f in ObjectWithList.DateList
          from s in OtherDateTimeList 
          where f == s
          select f;
```

Comment: I need this done in this LINQ as this is only a section of the over all LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) standard query operator:

```
var items = ObjectWithList.DateList.Intersect(OtherDateTimeList)
```

Comment: I need this done in this LINQ as this is only a section of the over all LINQ.